# Using single quote in replace?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am passing the following string into my Stored Procedure

```
'1,2,3,4,5,6'
```

I am trying to replace the , with ',' so that my string is translated to:

```
'1','2','3','4','5','6'
```

Is this possible? Here is my attempt:

```
Declare @Var2 varchar(250)
SET @Var2 = Replace(@Var1, ',', "','")
```

Comment: If you want to use that in an `IN()` clause then spare the time - it is not going to work with a single string, even if it contains `'`

Comment: Oh really? Dang, that's what I was going to do. Thanks

Comment: This may be just what you want: http://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/split-string-to-table-using-transact-sql/

Comment: Another option would be to create the entire statement using dynamic sql, then executing it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass a list of values as a parameter use a [table valued  parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The first step would be to create your type (I tend to go for a generic name so they can be reused):

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ListOfInt AS TABLE (Value INT);
```

Then you can pass as a parameter fairly easily:

```
DECLARE @T dbo.ListOfInt;
INSERT @T (Value) VALUES (1), (2), (3);

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM dbo.T WHERE ID IN (SELECT Value FROM @T)';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N'@T dbo.ListOfInt READONLY', @T;
```

Or create a procedure that takes the parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SomeProcName @IDs dbo.ListOfInt READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    -- DO SOMETHING
END
```

---

If this isn't an option, then pretty much everything you ever need to know about splitting strings in SQL Server is covered in the article [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) by Aaron Bertrand. He has done lots of testing so you can pick the best approach for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like below, you need to escape extra `'`

```
select replace(@Var1,',',''',''')
```

But doing that will result in something which you can't use in INLIST. So try like

```
select ''''+ replace('1,2,3,4,5,6',',',''',''') + ''''
```

Which will result in `'1','2','3','4','5','6'`